# join using multiple columns from different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

Big_Table has millions of records. Little_Table, a spreadsheet that will be reformatted and imported, has ~25,000 records. These tables share a few common and similar-but-expressed-differently columns that need to be matched, which are:

```
Big_Table
```

- common columns: **instr**, **date**, **ts**
- sample data:  `SPY20170602PUT241, 2017-06-01 09:21:20.107, 09:21:00.935`

`Little_Table`

- common columns: **Instrument**, **Date**, **Time**
- sample data:  `SPY20170602PUT241, 6/1/2017, 9:21:00`

**The objective is to retrieve records from Big_Table that match* Little_Table.  To do this, I need guidance on, I think, constructing/reformatting some Little_Table columns if necessary and then making a query that gets the job done.  Please advise**. 
*A match is where these three criteria are true for a row in each table:

```
- instr and instrument are the same exact string

 - date and Date indicate the same mm/dd/yyyy

 - ts and time indicate the same hh/mm/ss
```

Comment: Always store data using the correct data type for that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.  I created a new, modified version of Big_Table with custom-made column, **trade_name**.  I created Little_Table with the custom column **trade_name** as well, specifically to match on.  I doubt it's the best solution, but it worked.  Here are the details:

* **trade_name**, the engineered column, combines the three matching criterion which had originally been of mismatching formats and separate columns in each table, into a
format normalized, concatenated string (the date + the time + the instrument).  i.e. for each table, the columns that represented date, time and instrument were concatenated into the **trade_name** column, with like-formats.

1. *Creating Big_Table_New:* I used the CREATE TABLE statement from Big_Table, called it "Big_Table_New", removed keys, added column "trade name", made it the index of the table and then populated data using this statement:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Big_Table_New 
   SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(' | ',instr,DATE(date),TIME_FORMAT(ts,'%T')) 
   FROM Big_Table 
   WHERE date>='2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND date<'2017-06-02 00:00:00' 
   AND instr IN (SELECT instrument FROM instruments);
   ```

   I only needed records for the month of June 2017 and as a work-around, I repeated the query once for each day of the month, instead of selecting the entire month at once, since the query was getting timed out on one particular day of June.  Moving on...
2. *Creating Little_Table:* First I used CREATE TABLE Little_Table statement to make table schema.  I included a column for trade_name and made that the index.  Then I loaded the csv file, applying format modifications and concatenation for trade_name in the same step, using SET.

   ```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\myfilepath\\Little_File.csv' 
   INTO TABLE Little_Table
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
   ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
   IGNORE 1 LINES
   (l_instr, @l_date, @l_ts, l_prc, l_side, l_qty, trade_name)
   SET 
     l_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@l_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'),
     l_ts = TIME_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(@l_ts, '%H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR),'%T'),
     trade_name = CONCAT_WS(' | ',l_instr,l_date,l_ts);
   ```
3. The final query used this statement:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM Big_Table_New, Little_Table_New 
   WHERE Big_Table_New.`trade_name` = Little_Table_New.`trade_name`;
   ```

   The query took ~150 seconds, which was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this is a simple join on multiple conditios, try this example:

```
SELECT * FROM Big_Table JOIN Little_Table ON (instr=instrument AND date=Date AND ts=time) WHERE ....
```